# Umbraco: Nested content in Grid?

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to add Nested Content as an Editor when I want to add new Content to my grid property in an `Umbraco` solution.

But I am struggling to find out how to do this.
In the grid.editors.config.js I must add the new editor like so;

```
{
     "name": "Accordion",
     "alias": "accordion",
     "view": "rte",
     "icon": "icon-ordered-list"
}
```

But what do I reference under `view`? Currently, it is just referencing the `rte`. And/or, do I need to add anything else?
I am using the newest version of `Umbraco`, so the Nested Content is now part of the Core.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LeBlender in this case. It works like Nested Content but for Grid. One difference, it's not based on the document type.

[LeBlender](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/leblender/)